# Fixed Effects Estimation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Consider the following panel data regression model:

$$y_{it}=X_{it}\beta+\alpha_{i}+u_{it},$$ where $\alpha_{i}$ indicate
the nuisance parameters (indiviudal specific), $y_{it}$ is an $nt\times1$
vector of the dependent variable, $i$ represents individual $i$
, $t$ represents the time period, $X_{it}$ is an $nt\times k$ matrix
of the regressors, $\beta$ is a $k\times1$ vector of coefficients
that need to be estimated and $u_{it}$ is an $nt\times1$ vector of
the error terms assumed to be orthogonal to the regressors, conditional
on $\alpha_{i}$. When we estimate this panel data model by fixed
effects, we include a dummy variable for every individual, effectively
removing the nuisance paramter. This is equivalent to demeaning the
data and estimating $(y_{it}-\bar{y_{i})}=(X_{it}-\bar{X_{i}})\beta+(u_{it}-\bar{u})$.
In a sense, we are 'controlling' for time invariant individual unboservables
in order to get unbiased estimates of our parameters of interest.
Intuitively, I was wondering if the parameter estimates we obtain
are equivalent to estimating the coefficients *separetely* for
each individual and then averaging over all individuals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the true model is that you have homogeneity across the units, i.e. in the models $$y_{it}=X_{it}\beta_i+\alpha_i+u_{it}$$ we have $$\beta_i=\beta$$ then *pool mean group* estimator i.e. pooling everything and estimate $\beta$ is up to a statistically vanishing (with growing $(N,T)$) error the same as estimating each equation separately and the averaging (*mean group estimator*). Take a look at 1999 paper by Pesaran et. al. JASA. This is paper on dynamic models, but gives yo ua lot of insights!

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I was suggesting was then the mean group estimator. Please allow me to rephrase the question then: is the MG estimator identical to the fixed effects estimator? Thanks a lot!